# Smart App Banners not working

Tags: ios, iphone

Is it just me or the Smart App Banners stopped working? I use them on many of my client's pages, but since iOS 9 came along, the banner doesn't show app anymore offering people do install the available app.

e.g.:  this is one of them that are not working anymore, and the app is there, available.